# Change border color of a textbox inside it's onchange listener

Tags: c#, wpf

`myTextBox.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;` is working well outside the listener. But if I do it inside, no changes will appear.

Comment: Works fine for me, sounds like a theming issue.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Which IDE are using? I'm using VS 2017 with a simple project.

Comment: works great in my sample project.

Comment: I updated the question, because I found out the code is working outside the listener

Comment: You really need to post more code. As it stands, there is no way to answer your question. myTextBox.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red; works fine so your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 as well. So like @Sudsy1002 says, and as you've just indicated yourself, it looks like something else in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the textbox had focus while changing the color. A textbox with focus always have a blue border. The new color is only visible if the textbox loses focus. I decided to change the font color instead, to make the state instand visible.